# How to setup openai.createChatCompletion to return specific structured values via Prompt Engineering

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

How to setup openai API such that it returns a structured output

I want to train with two three examples or give context to the API such that for a new prompt it returns in the below structure and with specific values

```
{
        "primary": "#5D1049",
        "onPrimary": "#FFFFFF",
        "secondary": "#E30425",
        "onSecondary": "#FFFFFF",
        "surface": "#FFFFFF",
        "onSurface": "#000000",
        "background": "#F4E2ED",
        "onBackground": "#000000"
      }
```

The below is my API and I want a structured response

```
  const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      messages: [
        {"role": "system", "content": "You will be provided with brand name or mood and your task is to generate material color palette for the website in JSON format."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": generateResult()},
      ],
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
      temperature: 0.9,
      response_format: { type: "json_object" },
    });
```

I'm not sure how to provide examples to openai, there is an option to seed the API but need help with implementation